# Running Go Program which uses OpenVINO & OpenCV - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXXX

Tags: bash, opencv, go, openvino

I am trying to write a program in Go Programming Language that is using OpenVINO DNN models in order to perform inference. In order to do that I've followed instructions from this GITHUB link: https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/tree/master/openvino

I have installed OpenVINO and 3rd party libraries that go with it, this includes OpenCV which is located in `~/intel/openvino_{version}/opencv` directory.

Thing is whenever I try to execute following command:

```
go run -tags openvino ./cmd/version/main.go
```

I get this output:

```
 runtime/cgo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHeteroPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMKLDNNPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmyriadPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -linference_engine
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclDNNPlugin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_pvl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I tried to set my **CGO_LDFLAGS** like this:

```
CGO_LDFLAGS=-L/opencv/lib -L/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64 -lpthread -ldl -ldliaPlugin -lHeteroPlugin -lMKLDNNPlugin -lmyriadPlugin -linference_engine -lclDNNPlugin -lopencv_core -lopencv_pvl -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_video -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_calib3d
```

But when I do that I am getting:

```
bash: -L/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64: No such file or directory
```

Even though `~/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64` does exitst on my system.

Comment: my first thought - try with the absolute path

Comment: Already did. Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated (Feb/25/2020)

As of 2019 R3.334, OpenVINO SDK started supporting GoCV again.

---

### Old message

Check this out:

https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/issues/491

The recent version of openvino dropped the support of pvl so that there is no libpvl or something like that.

You can try one older version of it but there is no future.

Comment: I am sorry for late response. Are you saying that installing recent version of OPENVINO will fix the issue? Because in this guide I see you had to workaround it a lot and still did not find adequate solution, correct?

Comment: @StefanRadonjic, Opposite. As my comment as you can see there (https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/issues/491#issuecomment-516607015), the latest version of OpenVINO doesn't support PVL, which offers some feature for GoCV so that we cannot really use GoCV with OpenVINO anymore.

Comment: Aha, I understand. So in order to us GoCv with OpenVino I just have to follow your instructions on the issue and avoid using the latest version? Thank you for yur help btw.

Comment: @StefanRadonjic, Mostlikely, openvino_2019.1.144 would work because that version generates **libopencv_pvl.so** and you can just follow the normal instruction intriduced in GoCV's website.

Comment: @StefanRadonjic, It seems like GoCV and OpenVino started working together again (though I didn't check it yet). Please check this out https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/commit/9faa6a86b25221c0195d775a6b516f973b760179#diff-864a6fce7f45a0c59a4b6b029a0fd78e